# Change post date in menu to post title

Tags: posts

I'd like to have my posts displayed in the menu as a name, not as the date they're published. Is that possible?
Regards
Peter

Comment: to what menu are you referring? this is likely specific to the particular theme you're using.

Comment: The menu that displays my posts. Theme = twentyeleven

Answer (score 1):

You have to drag and drop the menu itens by hand, maybe some code can put the posts automatically there too.

About menus in WordPress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel